# When do you use a new method?

Tags: java

The simple way to print your name, age, and gender is to code it in one main method. Why do we have to make multiple methods to do this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    sayMaster();
    Age();
    Gender();
}

static void sayMaster() {
    System.out.println("Hello Master Austin");
}

static void Age() {
    System.out.println(7);
}

static void Gender() {
    System.out.println("Robot");
}
```

Comment: Who said you have to ?

Comment: You should ask the person who wrote that code.

Comment: I think the best answer is to get a copy of Robert Martin's "Clean Code" and read it.  That should explain why it's a good idea.  For very small methods like this, it may not be worthwhile to put everything in a new method, but it's a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 1):

> *Why do we have to make multiple methods to do this?*

actually you dont have to at all, but modularity is the key(remember the [divide et impera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_rule) rule), you can / need to change one of those methods latter with out a problem that your code will be broken...

then when you have those 3 methods you can always do an elegant solution like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    invokeThemAll(); 
}

public static void invokeThemAll() {
    sayMaster();
    printAge();
    printGender();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all no one forced you to make methods to just print 3 strings.

Making methods is preferable. Consider the scenario when you have to do this task 1000 times. Instead of writing print statement 1000 times you cab just call the method and send a parameter and rest will be done just by 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

In which of the examples can you immediately tell what the code is supposed to do?

**Example 1**

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    A a = new A();
    // CODE
    // CODE
    // CODE
    // CODE
    // ... 100 lines of setting up A
    B b = new B(a);
    // CODE
    // CODE
    // CODE
    // CODE
    // ... 100 lines of setting up B
    // CODE
    // CODE
    // CODE
    // CODE
    // ... 500 other lines of code using a and b
}
```

**Example 2**

```
public static A setupA() {
    A a = new A();
    // CODE
    // CODE
    // CODE
    // CODE
    // ... 100 lines of setting up A
    return a;
}

public static B setupB() {
    B b = new B();
    // CODE
    // CODE
    // CODE
    // CODE
    // ... 100 lines of setting up B
    return b;
}

public static void doFancyAlgorithm(A a, B b) {
    // CODE
    // CODE
    // CODE
    // CODE
    // 500 other lines of code using a and b
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    A a = setupA();
    B b = setupB();
    doFancyAlgorithm(a, b);
}
```

Clearly, example 2 would be easier to read and *understand*, because it's comprised of only 3 lines and because different responsibilities are encapsulated into different methods. You'd be able to understand what the main does just by looking at the sequence of methods, without knowing the actual implementation of said methods. Whereas in example 1 you'd need to wade through every line of code in order to understand.

Additionally, consider adding some new functionality to your code:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    A a = setupA();
    B b = setupB();
    doFancyAlgorithm(a, b);

    A a2 = setupA(); // new instance of a because we absolutely need that
    C c = setupC();
    doAnotherAlgorithm(a2, c);
}
```

Now in the case of setting up a new instance of `A`, we can simply **reuse** the method `setupA()` which makes everything easier. Otherwise we would need to rewrite the whole 100 lines of setting up A again.

This has another huge benefit. If you ever need to change some lines in your code, you'd only need to change it in **one place** (that is once inside the method instead of everywhere the code occurs), which prevents oversights, copy-paste errors, and so on.